# OpenSSL Java bindings for Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA)

Tags: java, cryptography, openssl, digital-signature, fips

I'm developing a Java project that needs to use a [FIPS 140-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2) validated module for crypto signatures. I'm leaning towards using the [OpenSSL FIPS Object Module](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html). After browsing around the webs, I couldn't find anything that implemented a Java bindings for OpenSSL in the Java Cryptography Architecture. I was wondering if anyone could point me to such a library, or an alternative approach to using OpenSSL in Java for crypto signatures.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think that such bindings exist, but it shouldn't be hard to create your own with JNA or JNI, especially if your required functionality is limited.

Answer (score 2):

Better use IBM FIPS compatible (140-2 level 1) JCE module which comes with IBM JRE. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v1r0/topic/com.ibm.rt.doc.10/security/jcefips/ibmjcefips.html

http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140crt/140crt1081.pdf

Comment: And of course, you can always use the Good Old Unix to execute OpenSSL command line tools from Java...

Comment: What are the licensing terms for this?

Comment: err.. IANAL but I believe you are free to execute any and all commands from your proprietary application. There is no linking happening.

Comment: No I mean for the IBMJCEFIPS... can I use it with my Oracle JRE? Do I have to buy Websphere to get it? Etc.

Comment: Don't know. It comes bundled with SLES for example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I hoped this might help others. Bouncy Castle provides a FIPS 140-2 Validated JCA provider.

https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips/UserGuide-20151229.pdf